# Using wordpress action to modify div content

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to modify a div's content everytime when something is added to the woocommerce shopping cart. For this example the content is gonna be the current total cart value.

So first I created a simple plugin called "test-cart-value" which contains the following code:

```
<?php

 function test_cart_value() {
    echo "<div>" . WC()->cart->total . "</div>";
}

add_shortcode('test_cart_value_shortcode', 'test_cart_value');
```

This works fine, wherever I place the shortcode I get the current cart value after page load.

So, now I want this printed value to updated every time something is added to the cart, without reloading the page. The idea was to use the action hook woocommerce_cart_updated and call the function - so everytime something in the cart changes, the new cart value gets echoed:

```
function action_woocommerce_cart_updated() { 
    test_cart_value();
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_updated', 'action_woocommerce_cart_updated', 10, 0 );
```

The problem is, now I'm not able to dynamically add products to the shopping cart. Whenever I hit the "add to cart" button, the loading animation loads forever.
How to do this properly?
I was trying different approaches with Ajax and different Hooks, but so far nothing worked.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

So I tried this as my plugin code

```
function test_cart_value() { 
    echo "<div id='cart_test'>" . WC()->cart->total . "</div>";
}

add_shortcode('test_cart_value_shortcode', 'test_cart_value');


// define the actions for the two hooks created, first for logged in users and the next for logged out users
add_action("woocommerce_cart_updated", "cart_update");

// define the function to be fired for logged in users
function cart_update() {

    $cart = WC()->cart->total;
    $result['type'] = "success";
    $result['new_cart'] = $cart;

    $result = json_encode($result);
    //if I uncomment the "die" function, the page won't load
//   die();
}

// Fires after WordPress has finished loading, but before any headers are sent.
add_action( 'init', 'script_enqueuer' );

function script_enqueuer() {

   // Register the JS file with a unique handle, file location, and an array of dependencies
   wp_register_script( "test_script", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'test_script.js', array('jquery') );

   // localize the script to your domain name, so that you can reference the url to admin-ajax.php file easily
   wp_localize_script( 'test_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   // enqueue jQuery library and the script you registered above
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'test_script' );
}
```

And my test_script.js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
   jQuery(".ajax_add_to_cart").click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "cart_update"},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               jQuery("#cart_test").html(response.new_cart);
            }
            else {
               alert("Your like could not be added");
            }
         }
      });
   });
});
```

So I thought that the cart_update() function should fire when I press the "ajax_add_to_cart" Button, but I get an error 400.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Try posting what you tried with AJAX and then maybe the SO community can help you debug it. PHP is server side, so it's only going to execute functions as the page loads, not after it's been loaded.  So doing it dynamically will require some javascripting and probably the use of AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added my code below.

Answer (score 0):

made it work with woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments.